# how do I iterate through hash of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am new to ruby and would like to find out how I can iterate through the following hash inside this array.

Here is my code:

```
x = {:country => "china", :people=>'chinese'}
y = {:country => "india", :people=>'indians'}
z = {:country => "iran", :people=>'iranians'}

countries = [x, y, z]
```

I would like for my code to spit out:

' you have 3 countries'

The name of the first one is: china
The name of the second is: india
the name of the third is Iran

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`? How are they relevant to the question? Where does the information regarding the three countries come from? Do you want to collect all local variables whose class is a hash? Or, all local variables whose name is a single letter belonging to the latter half of the alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean:

```
x = {:country => "china", :people=>'chinese'}
y = {:country => "india", :people=>'indians'}
z = {:country => "iran", :people=>'iranians'}

countries = [x, y, z]
```

If so you can get count by doing

```
puts "You have #{countries.size}"
```

For each country name output you could do:

```
countries.each_with_index do |country, index|
  puts "#{index}. #{country[:country]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {:country => "china", :people=>'chinese'}
y = {:country => "india", :people=>'indians'}
z = {:country => "iran", :people=>'iranians'}

countries = [x, y, z]

countries.each.with_index(1) do |value, index|
   puts "The name of country #{index} is #{value[:country]}"
end
```